# Why is Big O of Bubble sort Quadradic time if last interaction is dismissed?

Tags: c#, big-o, bubble-sort, asymptotic-complexity

I have the following Bubble sort Algorithm:

```
    public void BubbleSort(int[] arr, int start, int end)
    {
        int instructions = 0;
        bool swapped = true;

        while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                //instructions++;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    instructions++;
                    if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                    {
                        int temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;

                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("instructions++ " + instructions);
    }
```

if you print `instructions` you will see it is exactly: (n^2) - n

So why do we disregard -n?

Is it considered constant even though it is variable to the input size(it would be weird buy hey..)?

Answer (score 2):

Time compelxity works as such. For large n values in this case, linear n does not matter. For eg if we are talking about 10 million numbers the value (10^6)^2 is far greater than 10^6. So even though it exists the other factor dwarfs it for large n so it makes it easier to disregard it.

Comment: I think that would be true if there were: O(n^2) + O(n). But that's no the case, it was not even n^2 so why the reason to define is as quadradic in the fist place?

Comment: O(n^2+n) can be written as O(n^2)+O(n). If you were to visualize bubble sort you can see that the highest element travel n distance the second highest n-1 and so on in the worst case. This means the sum of movements is (1+2+...+n-1+n) which is n(n-1)/2 movements which essentially boils down to n^2-n and this can be simplifies to n^2.